# Partial derivative of $f(x,y(x))$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have $f(x,y) = \sin(x^2+y^2)$ where $y(x)=\sqrt{3\pi - x^2}$ and I am trying to find $f_x=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y(x_0))$

What I tried doing is:
$$ \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac {\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot \frac {\partial y}{\partial x}$$ which gives me
$$2x\cdot \cos(3\pi)+2\cdot\sqrt{3\pi-x^2}\cdot \cos(3\pi)\cdot \frac {-x}{\sqrt{3\pi-x^2}}$$

and that's equal to $0$.. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $f(x,y)=0$ by your definition ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you got $0$!

With your hypothesis, $f(x, y(x))$ is constant. Let us look at it more carefully:

$$f(x, y(x)) = sin\left(x^2 + y(x)^2\right) = sin\left(x^2 + (3\pi - x^2)\right) = sin(3\pi) = 0$$

That is enough to have $\dfrac{df\left(x, y(x)\right)}{dx} = 0$